# Who created the character Darth Bane?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas

I was having a debate with this guy on YouTube and was wondering, was it George Lucas who created this character along with the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two)? The only two quotes I could find about it were these on [Comicvine.com](http://www.comicvine.com/darth-bane/4005-44794/) and the [Starwars wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane#Character_origins).

Both state Lucas created him, but I was wondering if it is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first mention of Darth Bane within the Star Wars EU is in the [novelisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel)) of "The Phantom Menace" by Terry Brooks. This reference predates all of the other media that he appears in.

Given that this book is "*Based on the Screenplay and Story by George Lucas*" we can reasonably assume that Bane was an original invention of George Lucas that simply didn't make it into the film:

> The Sith who had survived when all of his fellows had died had
>   understood that. He had adopted patience as a virtue when the others
>   had forsaken it. He had adopted cunning, stealth, and subterfuge as
>   the foundation of his way—old Jedi virtues the others had disdained.
>   He stood aside while the Sith tore at each other like kriks and were
>   destroyed. When the carnage was complete, he went into hiding, biding
>   his time, waiting for his chance.
>
> When it was believed all of the Sith were destroyed, he emerged from
>   his concealment. At first he worked alone, but he was growing old and
>   he was the last of his kind. Eventually, he went out in search of an
>   apprentice. Finding one, he trained him to be a Master in his turn,
>   then to find his own apprentice, and so to carry on their work. But
>   there would only be two at any one time. There would be no repetition
>   of the mistakes of the old order, no struggle between Siths warring
>   for power within the cult. Their common enemy was the Jedi, not each
>   other. It was for their war with the Jedi they must save themselves.
>
> **The Sith who reinvented the order called himself Darth Bane.**
>
> <sub><sup>- The Phantom Menace : Chapter 10</sup></sub>

This is backed up by the now-defunct "[The New Essential Chronology](http://web.archive.org/web/20080611114115/http://www.starwars.com/eu/lit/ref/f20051025/indexp2.html)" page on starwars.com which explictly states that Bane's first mention is in the novelisation and comes from Lucas' back-story for the Sith:

> But the events of Ruusan were still just ancient history until the
>   Jedi vs. Sith comic. It consisted of six issues published monthly in
>   2001 from Dark Horse Comics. The fall-out from the battle continued in
>   a short story titled "Bane of the Sith," published in Star Wars Gamer
>   magazine #3 (2001, Wizards of the Coast), which dramatizes Darth
>   Bane's arrival on Dxun. **The character of Bane and his secret
>   reformation of the Sith order actually come from George Lucas'
>   back-story to Episode I.**

Comment: "he trained **him**" wasn't Darth Bane's apprentice female?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - Not according to Lucas. I wouldn't get too hung up though since all of the EU books are considered quite far down the food-chain as far as canonicity is concerned. They frequently contradict each other and, occasionally the films.

Comment: @Richard or the movies ignore them depending on what was created first.